# What kind of switch can I use for remote control of patio lights?

Tags: remote-control

Any suggestions on replacing the outdoor rocker on/off switch (on the left) with a remote switch that could be controlled from inside of our condo? The switch is currently used to control our outdoor patio lights. I want to avoid drilling through so many inches of slump block (building material used here in Tucson back in the 80's). Of course, the signal would have to travel unimpeded through the block. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the lights plugged into the receptacle next to the switch? Or is the receptacle always on and the switch controls hardwired lights?

Comment: It's the latter: the switch controls the six hardwired lights and the receptacle is always on.

Comment: I figured that was the case. So the first answer won't do because it is based on plug/cord connected lights.

Comment: any smart switch will do, there's 100s to choose from.

Comment: Does the wiring arrive here in conduit, or is it cables embedded in the wall? If conduit, easy to change it to a 3-way with the other switch (wifi/smart if you like) in the house.

Comment: The rocker switch has two hot wires going into it controlling the patio lights. I'm not interested in interfacing with Alexa (or any of her relatives!), or a smart phone. I simply want a remote 'clicker' I can control from inside the house using RF through two layers of slump ('cider' for the East Coasters!) block.

Comment: So, you want a product recommendation? That's specifically off-topic.

Comment: Well, yes. . . though I don't know if that's allowed in a forum like this but I find the choices out there a little bewildering when all I want is something very simple — at least from my perspective!

Comment: As for the site expectations, looks like you haven't taken the [tour]. Simplest thing would be to add some wires to the conduit, but you haven't said if there is a conduit. You might need a time machine back to the 1980's  to find a "non-smart RF-controlled switch" now. And RF does not love traveling through dirt, concrete, or cinderblock anyway, so that part's a bit of an ask.

Comment: Thanks! I thought as much! I may stick to my original plan and have an electrician drill through the block and feed the wires through into a wall-mounted indoor switch.

Comment: Do you have the lights on each night?  You could consider to replace the bulbs with dusk to dawn bulbs and leave the switch always on.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I didn't even know such a thing existed! I'll look into them. Again, than you!

Answer (score 1):

I found many that would work in the same Decora style and they were not that expensive. Search for "wall mount rf switch with remote" or "wall mount rf switch with remote Decora" , I found some were even in stock at some of the big box stores.

Answer (score -1):

My first suggestion would be to use a wifi controlled switch. As an example **Amazon Smart Plug**

[image]

or Wemo Wi-Fi Smart Outdoor Plug

[image]

They have their own apps to control them.

Comment: Looking at the photo of the lights, I believe the lights are **hard-wired** to the switch. The outlet is presumably being used for something else.

Comment: Thank you Rohit for the suggestion though I think I'm looking for another option. The outlet has a Defiant remote switch used to control a fountain and another lighting configuration.